# Identify this bird call?

Tags: birds, bird-watching, bird-identification

Could somebody please identify the birdcall in [this recording](http://game-point.net/misc/BirdCall.mp3)?  The bird is calling at 00:01, 00:10, 00:29, 00:36, 00:52, 01:06, and 01:18.  This recording was made in England, in mid-June.

Also, how do you quiet these birds down?  The call is very noisy and annoying.

Comment: Liam's identification is correct. Unfortunately, all my research confirms it as an extremely noisy bird, which doesn't even have a reliable quiet time! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a magpie

Here's a copy of an [identical call from the British Library archive](http://sounds.bl.uk/Environment/British-wildlife-recordings/022m-w1cdr0001537-2800v0)

[image]